# file uploading using ftp_put

Tags: php, ftp

I have solved my original question below. What is the best method if I need to insert a progress bar for the file uploader? Using the ftp_put method, doesn't allow to get a response from the server until the file is successfully uploaded.

Thanks!

---

I'm trying to upload a file using **ftp_put** and for some reason when I run the code through localhost, it gives me the below error:

> Warning: ftp_put(): Can't open that file: Is a directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ftp\upload_file.php on line 25

```
<form action="upload_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "";
$ftp_user_name = "";
$ftp_user_pass = "";
$destination_file = "/public_html/testing/";
$source_file = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']; 

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 

// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
    echo "FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
    echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}
// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Found out the issue. I had to provide the exact file name for the $destination_file without just providing the directory :-) but what if I don't know the name of the file? As I have used an upload button, it could be any file.

Answer (score 1):

Please test chdir that destination or look at [this on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php#Hcom89986)

```
    Got this cryptic error

Warning:  ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: 'STOR' not understood in
C:\wamp\www\kevtest\ftp_todays.php on line 48

Found the prob, you can't put a path to the destination file
(even though I can do that in the dos ftp client...?)

e.g. - this doesn't work
ftp_put($conn, '/www/site/file.html','c:/wamp/www/site/file.html',FTP_BINARY);

you have to put

<?php
ftp_chdir($conn, '/www/site/');
ftp_put($conn,'file.html', 'c:/wamp/www/site/file.html', FTP_BINARY );
?>
```

Comment: Found the answer :-) $destination_file = "/public_html/testing/".$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                ini_set('max_execution_time', 60000);

        $file = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];
        $destination_file = "/public_html/".time().basename($_FILES['video']['name']);
        // connect and login to FTP server
        $ftp_server = ".com";
        $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
        $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, 'name', 'pass');

        // upload file
        if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $destination_file, $file, FTP_BINARY))
          { echo "Successfully uploaded ".$_FILES['video']['name']." "; }
        else
          { echo "Error uploading $file.";  }

        // close connection
        ftp_close($ftp_conn);
        }
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <body>
        <div class="container">
        <form name="frm" id="frm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="file" name="video" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="move()"/>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>

        </body>

        </html>
```

Comment: Here everything is fine but video with Large size gives
Warning: ftp_put(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\ftp.php on line 15